# ActionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response.Body is not readable in IActionFilter of asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm now migrate a classical **Asp.Net WebAPI** project to **Asp.Net Core**. And previous, there was an action filter to log each response info. But it not working since the new body object in .net core is not readable.

Here is what my code in asp.net core (2.0):

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public class Startup (in Startup.cs)
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Added for invoke custome filter
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add<ActionLogFilter>();
        });
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

`ActionLogFilter.cs`

```cs
public class ActionLogFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
      //...
      var responseBody = ReadResponseBody(actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response);
      //...
    }

    private static string ReadResponseBody(HttpResponse response)
    {
        var initialBody = response.Body;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.Body)) // throw exception here
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        finally
        {
            response.Body = initialBody;
        }
    }
}
```

Complete error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
> at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
> at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream).

I tried to use MemorySteam but not working at all since the original object is NOT readable at all.

Any idea to get response details information?

Or other alternate solution?